# Unity3D: HighScore

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay to be basic, I have a 2d top down game on unity. The premises of my game is to collect as much coins as you can before you die. I used player pref so that when a player get the highest score it will save the person's score. However I am facing a problem, which is; when you first play the game, you collect coins then die, the game then saves the highest point you got and displays it on a panel that comes down, BUT if you play the game again and don't collect any coins, then the game doesn't show the highest point you got, instead it will show "0". So to sum up if I don't collect any coins and I die then the panel will come down and show 0 as my high score. So I have to get at least 1 coin for it to show the person highest high score. Which is not want I want, want I want is for when the player dies, regardless of how many coins you have collected,  it will show (in my panel) your highest high score the person got to. Does anyone knows how to fix this??? Thank you. 
This is my code:

```
public Text ScoreText;
public Text Highscoretext;
public AudioClip coinsound;
public int Score;
public int highScore = 0;

    void Start () 
{
    Score = 0;
    SetScoreText ();

    if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("Highscore")) 
    {
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore");
    }
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pick Up")) 
    {
        other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
        Score = Score + 1;
        SetScoreText ();
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (coinsound, transform.position);        
    }
}

void SetScoreText ()
{
    ScoreText.text = "Score: " + Score.ToString ();
    Highscoretext.text = "Highscore" + highScore.ToString ();
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two playerpref variables. "ScoreThisPlaySesssion" and "HighestScoreEver" count score this session up when you collect coins and when that is higher than "highest score ever" count that up with one value evert time you get a coin.

```
void Start () 
{
Score = 0;
SetScoreText ();

if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("Highscore")) 
{
    highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore");
}
 }
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
     if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Pick Up")) 
    {
    other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
    Score = Score + 1;
    SetScoreText ();
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (coinsound, transform.position);        
}
}

void SetScoreText ()
 {
   ScoreText.text = "Score: " + Score.ToString ();
   if( PlayerPrefs.GetInt( "highestscoreever", 0 ) < Score ) 
      PlayerPrefs.SetInt( "highestscoreever", Score );
      Highscoretext.text = "Highscore" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt( "highestscoreever", 0 );
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, I really appreciate it